# Creating a new many-to-many table

Tags: sql, mysql, many-to-many

I have a database Class_Books which links ISBNs (from Books table) to Class_ID's (from Classes table).  I'm changing my Books table so the primary key is a Book_ID (autoincrement INT) instead of the ISBN.  Is there a way to update Class_Books so it uses Book_ID now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports a multi-table UPDATE syntax that makes this type of work a lot easier.

```
ALTER TABLE Class_Books ADD COLUMNS Book_Id INT; -- nullable

UPDATE Books b JOIN Class_Books cb ON b.ISBN = cb.ISBN
SET cb.Book_Id = b.Book_Id;
```

Then you can use ALTER TABLE to change the constraints, make cb.Book_Id `NOT NULL`, and drop cb.ISBN.

PS: I recommend calling Class_Books a *many-to-many* table or an *intersection* table.  The word *relation* means something different in relational theory, and it has nothing to do with relationships between tables.

Comment: Is that the same thing as an *association* table? Or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: @mlschechter: Sounds like a synonym to me

Comment: Sure, just don't call it a *relation table* because that'd be like saying you're using a *number integer*.  Sort of true in a way, but it sounds awkward and redundant.